# Can you Remote Desktop the Wine window itself?

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, wine

I am trying to find a way of being able to start a Remote Desktop connection to control the Wine Desktop itself. This is because I am running some programs inside of Wine which I would like to be able to be controlled, but not my whole Ubuntu desktop. Is there a Remote Desktop server out there which will control the programs running inside of Wine?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running an X server on your local system then you can use X forwarding over SSH to view the X client (wine app) on the local system.